# In a Wordpress theme. Html hyperlink, li with image and text on top not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, syntax, wordpress-theming

I need some help with the code below, I'm unable to get the `ahref` to work once I insert the text which needs to be displayed on top of the image.

```
<?php 
  $pages = get_pages('child_of=32'); 
  if ($pages) { 
  echo '<ul>'; 
  foreach ($pages as $page) { 
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'; 
  echo '<div class="you-section-div"><h3>';
  echo get_the_title($page->ID);
  echo '</h3>';
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); 
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</a></li>'; 
  } 
  echo '</ul>'; 
  } 
  ?>
```

If I remove the title everything works as it should but no matter which way I try and insert text it kills the link and also confuses the firefox inspector into thinking your highlighting a different element further down the page.

Any help welcome :)
Thanks

Comment: Why use </ul> outside the if ($pages)?

Comment: Try to separate the link to 2 links, one a tag around the image and one a tag around the title

Comment: @Jeroen Heier  otherwise it will be in the loop

Comment: Can you create a snippet and show the generated html and if possible add the css too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, wrapping the image and text with separated A tags:

```
<?php 
$pages = get_pages('child_of=32'); 

if ($pages) { 
   echo '<ul>'; 
  foreach ($pages as $page) { 
     echo '<li>'; 
     echo '<div class="you-section-div"><h3>';
     echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'. get_the_title($page->ID). '</a>';
     echo '</h3>';
     echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'). '</a>'; 
     echo '</div>';
     echo '</li>'; 
   } 
   echo '</ul>'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: no luck, I think I tried something similar. do you think it is something to do with the li tag? thanks

Comment: Could you add a link to the page? It will be easier to see what's wrong

Comment: I can't as it's on my local machine. I've changed the z-index on '<div class="you-section-div">' to 10 and that made the link clickable. though the text isn't selectable, I'm not sure if this is a problem for so or not?